# Sorting an array and retrieving the sorted index

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, indexing, time-complexity

I want to sort the array by his indices.

Look at the code below:

```
var distances = [530, 0, 24, 335, 274, 591];

console.log(sortIndex(distances));

function sortIndex(toSort) {
  return toSort.map(
    (e,i) => {return {index: i, value: e};}
  ).sort(
    (a,b) => a.value - b.value
  ).map(
    (e,i) => {return e.index;},[]
  );
}
```

The output is:

```
[1, 2, 4, 3, 0, 5]
```

Can someone tell me how to reduce the complexity of this snippet? This algorithm is `O(n^3)` and I wonder if you can solve the same problem with a better solution?

Anyone out there? Thanks.

Comment: This algorithm does not have `O(n^3)` complexity. It has `O((n) + (n log n) + (n)) = O(n log n)` complexity. The first `map` is `O(n)`, the sort is `O(n log n)`, and the final map is `O(n)`. When we add those steps together, the remaining complexity is `n log n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could obtain a better *performance* by creating a `copy` of the array and a `hash` structure of indexes where the complexity is `O(N)` because we're iterating the array only once.

```js
var distances = [530, 0, 24, 335, 274, 591];
var copy = Object.assign([], distances);

var indexes = distances.reduce((hash, elem, i) => {
  hash[elem] = i;
  return hash;
}, {});

sortIndex = (toSort) => toSort.sort().map(el => indexes[el]);
console.log(sortIndex(copy));
```

So, the *final* complexity of the algorithm is the complexity of `sort` plus the complexity of the `map` function.

For the `sort` the complexity is `Θ(n log(n))`.

For the `map` method the complexity is `O(n)` because you're iterating the array only once to *map* every item through a `callback` provided *function*.

Comment: Would this work if distances[] has duplicate values?

Comment: @gihef, unfortunately, no. For duplicate values you need to use `indexOf` method instead creating a hash structure.

Answer (score 1):

I am actually thinking of having the problem solved using a `TreeMap` which holds the keys in ascending order and can store the indexes as the value for the key. In that way, we can have the duplicate values indexed properly and I suppose solving the problem using a `TreeMap` should have `O(n log n)` complexity.

Here is my working code in Java.

```
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld {

     public static void main(String []args){
        int arr[] = {530, 0, 24, 335, 274, 591};

        int sortedIndexes[] = getSortedIndexes(arr);
        printSortedIndexes(sortedIndexes); 
     }

     public static void printSortedIndexes(int[] printArr) {
         for (int element : printArr) {
             System.out.print(element + " ");
         }
     }

     public static int[] getSortedIndexes (int[] arr) {
         TreeMap<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new TreeMap<>();

         for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
             if (map.containsKey(arr[i])) {
                 List<Integer> indexes = map.get(arr[i]);
                 indexes.add(i);
             } else {
                 List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<>();
                 indexes.add(i);
                 map.put(arr[i], indexes);
             }
         }

         // Now get the elements from the LinkedHashMap 
         int[] result = new int[arr.length];
         int counter = 0;

         for( Map.Entry<Integer, List<Integer>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            Integer key = entry.getKey();
            List<Integer> indexes = entry.getValue();

            for (int index : indexes) {
                result[counter] = index;
                counter++;
            }
        }

        return result;
     }
}
```

The `TreeMap` itself has `O(log n)` complexity for insertion and lookup. I am taking a map of `<Integer, Lis<Integer>>` so that we can store the values from the given array as keys and the indexes of the values as a `List` under that key (this is to handle the duplicate cases). If there is no duplicate in the input, we can get rid of the `List<Integer>` and just can have the `TreeMap<Integer, Integer>`.

I hope that helps.